# Powershell: Results in straight tab/column & limited error message output

Tags: powershell, error-handling, tabs

apologies in advance, I am a complete programming noob, and just know enough to be dangerous, but kinda through a lot of (confusing) trial and error can kinda exit pre-existing scripts, but can't build one myself.

Here's what I have: I have a script that puts a bunch of computers in an AD group that is fed in via a text file:

```
cls
$ListSingle = Get-Content -path "c:\powershell\ListSingle.txt"

#Select the target OU
cls
$OUDN = "OU=*AD PATH*"

#Confirm selections
cls
Write-Host "You have selected to move the following PCs to the OU listed:" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host ""
ForEach ($PC in $ListSingle) {Write-Host $($PC) "`t will be moved to:" $OUDN}
Write-Host ""
Pause

#Move PCs based on selections made

ForEach ($PC in $ListSingle)
{
  $ADObject = Get-ADComputer $($PC) 
  Move-ADObject -Identity $ADObject.DistinguishedName -TargetPath $OUDN
  $ADObject = Get-ADComputer $($PC)
  Write-Host "New OU for"$($PC) "is:`t"(Get-ADComputer $($PC)).DistinguishedName
}
```

[image]

**Question 1)** As you can see, the tab for the second group works if the computer name is a certain length, but if not, it doesn't align properly. I tried added two tabs, but the same result happens. How can I create something that keep the results 'straight'?

**Question 2)** If a computer is not found (for example deleted), it outputs a bunch of error messages, which is good to know that it didn't work, however for lots of computers, this becomes a mess. I don't need all the error text- I'd like to limit it to just the first line. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance, and please forgive the stupid questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner like you but can suggest a few things looking at the script. For errors, you may search how to write your script using Try/Catch blocks. That way you can have a custom message setup for failing records.

For the names that do not completely appear, try exporting the records to a csv file rather then writing host. From my learning, I have seen this issue get resolved for a majority of cases when you export.